# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable . MFCC

Tags: python, numpy, speaker, mfcc

Working on a project based on speaker recognition using python and  getting the following error while finding `MFCC`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "neh1.py", line 10, in <module>
    complexSpectrum = numpy.fft(signal)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This is the part of code:

```
import numpy
from scipy.fftpack import dct
from scipy.io import wavfile
sampleRate, signal = wavfile.read("/home/neha/Audio/b6.wav")
numCoefficients = 13 # choose the sive of mfcc array
minHz = 0
maxHz = 22.000
complexSpectrum = numpy.fft(signal)
powerSpectrum = abs(complexSpectrum) ** 2
filteredSpectrum = numpy.dot(powerSpectrum, melFilterBank())
logSpectrum = numpy.log(filteredSpectrum)
dctSpectrum = dct(logSpectrum, type=2)
```

What would be the issue?

Comment: `numpy.fft` is a module containing lots of variations of fft functions.  You want `numpy.fft.fft()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` means you're trying to use something like a function when it's not actually a function or a method (e.g. doing `foo()` when `foo` is an `int` or a module).  As @JohnGordon points out, `numpy.fft` is a module, but you're calling it like a function.  You want to use `numpy.fft.fft() to do what you want.

See the [`numpy.fft` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft) for more functions related to fast Fourier Transforms.